# Blender trying to bake the Color with Shaders(Cycles)

Tags: shaders, texture-baking

I connected a few nodes in “Shading” to create an interesting gemstone-ish texture for my object.I chose the baking type “diffuse” because of the color input.
Sadly everything came out black.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to replace the duplicated screenshot by a full screenshot of your shader, as well as your baking settings, so that we can see what's going on.  Please do your best to make readable screenshots, no low resolution nor zoomed out stuff that wee need to see. Unrelated, but there's already an emission component in the Principled BSDF node, you shouldn't need these extra Emission BSDF + Mix Shader nodes.